# Split a vector into 2 subranges without reallocating memory

Tags: c++, stl

Let's say I have a container (vector) `cont` and an iterator `split` pointing somewhere in the container.

I want to obtain two subranges [`cont.begin()`, split) and [split, `cont.end()`) using the memory of the initial container - or maybe the initial container will shrink to the first subrange and the remaining memory will be stolen by the second.

If I was working with manually allocated arrays, I'd have someting like :

```
double *cont; // the 'container' - memory was allocated for this
int sz;       // the size of the container
int cap;      // the capacity of the container
```

Then (since I'm manually doing the bookeeping) I could introduce a new 'container'

```
double *slice = cont + split; // in this context split is an index and not an iterator
int slice_sz  = sz - split;
int slice_cap = capacity - split;
```

So then the 'container' would be updated as

```
sz -= split;
cap = split;
```

Is this doable with STL ? Can I use the existing chunk of memory and have two containers with updated members (size, capacity etc ... I suppose the hack of passing `.data` has no meaning)

### PS

I'm aware the standard solution would be to work with iterator ranges, but I have a context where I need to work with complete containers, so [begin, split) and [split, end) is not any good.

Comment: Can you say what that context is? There's no way to split the (single, contiguous block of) memory owned by a vector into two blocks owned by separate vectors. You could just _copy_ the second, or the smaller, split range into another container, but I assume you want to avoid that.

Comment: You may use a specific `allocator` to use some shared buffer memory...

Comment: @Useless Yes, I'm using an API (lets call it a set of functions better) that does not accept iterators as input; it mandates passing `const &container` and I can't change those functions

Comment: Is the container passed to the API a concrete type, or a template type parameter? If the API is templated on container type, you can use a vector-like facade for your iterator range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a specific `allocator`, you may *share* the memory.
Something like the following may help:

```
template <typename T>
struct buffer_allocator
{
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using value_type = T;

    buffer_allocator(T* buffer, std::size_t max_size) :
        buffer(buffer), max_size(max_size)
    {}

    template<typename... Args>
    void construct(T* p, Args&&... args)
    { /*::new((void *)p) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);*/ }

    void destroy(T* p) { /*p->~T();*/ }

    T* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        if (max_size != n) { throw std::bad_alloc{}; }
        return buffer;
    }

    void deallocate(T*, std::size_t) {}

    std::size_t get_max_size() const { return max_size; }

private:
    T* buffer;
    std::size_t max_size;
};
```

And use it that way: (https://ideone.com/MaDYPZ)

```
std::vector<int> v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
buffer_allocator<int> b1(v.data(), 3);
buffer_allocator<int> b2(v.data() + 3, v.size() - 3);
std::vector<int, buffer_allocator<int>> v1(b1.get_max_size(), b1);
std::vector<int, buffer_allocator<int>> v2(b2.get_max_size(), b2);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't have two "containers", but you can have two iterator ranges.

```
vector<double> v;
vector<double>::iterator split = v.begin() + offset;

do_something(v.begin(), split);
do_something(split, v.end());
```

So the question becomes, what sort of operations do you want to perform on your two ranges?

Comment: I think I upated before the post, or at least simultaneously :P. Anyway sorry for not mentining that before, I agree with what you say, +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

As you already mention slices, you could have a look at `std::valarray` and see if that fits your requirements better.

```
std::valarray v(n);
auto first = v.slice(0, split, 1);
auto second = v.slice(split, v.size() - split, 1);
```

This gives you two slices referencing the original valarray.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to use std::list instead of std::vector? The list container has a splice function that can be used to move elements between lists:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/splice/

This is mostly possible because list is usually implemented as a linked list.